# 'Type Mismatch' when calling DateDiff function

Tags: excel, vba

Getting 'type mismatch' here. What is my coding issue?

Coded into Module 1:

```
Function NumberofRows(pDate1 As Date, pDate2 As Date) As Integer
NumberofRows = DateDiff("d", pDate1, pDate2) + 6
End Function
```

Coded into Userform: (will be called by command button)

```
Private Sub InsertRows()
Dim i As Integer
i = NumberofRows("SDI", "EDI")

Worksheets(5).Rows("5:" & i).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

End Sub
```

SDI and EDI are named cells within the document that are a Start Date and End Date.

Comment: Pass range("SDI").value as "SDI" on it's own is just a string, not a date

Comment: You are an amazing human being, I have been struggling with this for way too long. Thank you!